# What happens to variance and expectation when normal variable is squared?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given a normal variable $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Let $F = X^2$.

How does the $\mu$ and the $\sigma^2$ of $F$ change from those of X.

Comment: The expectation $E[F]=E[X^2]=\mu^2+\sigma^2$.  This could be equal to $\mu$ but usually is not

Comment: Heard of a "chi-squared distribution"?

Comment: ... though in this case it could be a scaled non-central chi-squared distribution

Comment: What @Henry wrote is not totally correct. The mean would be that only if X is independent of itself which is not the case in here. Check for a " random variable independent of itself"   and you will find some answers.
I agree on looking for the chi-squared distribution. Lots of fun!.

Comment: @htennek2k - Are you saying that there are examples of random variables $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ which do not have $E[X^2] = \mu^2+\sigma^2$? If so, I would be very interested in an example.  Or are you saying this is never equal to $\mu$? If so, consider the case of  $\mu=\frac12$ and $\sigma^2=\frac14$

Comment: Do I need to use a moment generating function in order to calculate $X^2$